# Slicing a file's contents into parts and saving them in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck in a rather simple looking problem and could not figure out after searching on internet. I have a file which have xyz coordinates of different chemical structures in it. I have to read the file and separate all the coordinates and save them in a list of lists of lists where one structure will be saved as a list of lists.

Here are the file contents:

```
4
C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
C         11.74100       -0.16400       11.81700
H         10.89900       -0.07300       11.12700
H         12.06500        0.84600       12.09300
H         11.37900       -0.66000       12.72200
4
C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
C         10.85300       -0.88000        9.22400
H         10.72700        0.08200        8.72200
H         10.13800       -0.92800       10.05300
H         10.59300       -1.66500        8.51000
4
C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
C         11.24200       -2.12500        9.34300
H         10.31400       -1.67400        8.98400
H         11.00100       -2.76200       10.20000
H         11.63100       -2.76500        8.54700
4
C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
C         10.27500       -0.28000       10.38600
H         10.06700        0.36400       11.24300
H          9.67000       -1.18700       10.48700
H          9.94500        0.24600        9.48600
4
C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
C         11.30600        1.51100        7.15800
H         11.68900        1.85800        6.19600
H         11.53100        2.27500        7.91000
H         10.21900        1.43100        7.07500
```

I also do not want first two lines of every structure coordinates. Here is the code I tried:

```
input_file = 'vega_str.xyz'
open_file = open(input_file, 'r')
first_lett = str(open_file.readline())
print(first_lett)
conformers = []
geom = []

f = open(input_file, 'r')
for line in f:
    if line.find(first_lett) == 1:
        del geom[:] 
        readStructure = f.__next__()
        while True:
            readStructure = f.__next__()
            if readStructure.find(first_lett) == -1: 
                readStructure = readStructure.split()
                geom.append(readStructure) 
        else:
            break
        for i in geom:
            del i[0:3:2]
        conformers.append(geom)
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
conformers = [[['C', 11.74100, -0.16400, 11.81700], ['H, 10.89900, -0.07300,
11.12700], ['H, 12.06500, 0.84600, 12.09300], ['H', 11.37900, -0.66000,
12.72200], [['C', 10.85300, -0.88000, 9.22400], ['H, 10.72700, 0.08200,
8.72200], ['H, 10.13800, -0.92800, 10.05300], ['H', 10.59300, -1.66500,
8.51000]]....]
```

Please help here. I would be really thankful.

Comment: What output did you get and how did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

how about something like

```
def file_formatter(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        return [list(
            filter(lambda i: i if i else '',
                   line.strip().split(' '))
            ) for line in file.readlines()]

file_names = ['test_file', ]
print([file_formatter(file) for file in file_names])
[[['C', '11.30600', '1.51100', '7.15800'], ['H', '11.68900', '1.85800', '6.19600'], ['H', '11.53100', '2.27500', '7.91000'], ['H', '10.21900', '1.43100', '7.07500']]]
```

Comment: Hi dparadis28,
Thank you so much for your time. This code is only giving me a list of lists but I want a list of list of lists where there are 5 lists of lists in the main list with the respective coordinates. Could you please help debugging where is the problem?

`Thanks`

Answer (score 0):

If the number is suppose to specify the number of atoms to be listed, then you could try to see where blind trust will lead you:

```
In [19]: import io

In [20]: from itertools import islice

In [22]: source = r"""4
    ...: C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
    ...: C         11.74100       -0.16400       11.81700
    ...: H         10.89900       -0.07300       11.12700
    ...: H         12.06500        0.84600       12.09300
    ...: H         11.37900       -0.66000       12.72200
    ...: 4
    ...: C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
    ...: C         10.85300       -0.88000        9.22400
    ...: H         10.72700        0.08200        8.72200
    ...: H         10.13800       -0.92800       10.05300
    ...: H         10.59300       -1.66500        8.51000
    ...: 4
    ...: C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
    ...: C         11.24200       -2.12500        9.34300
    ...: H         10.31400       -1.67400        8.98400
    ...: H         11.00100       -2.76200       10.20000
    ...: H         11.63100       -2.76500        8.54700
    ...: 4
    ...: C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
    ...: C         10.27500       -0.28000       10.38600
    ...: H         10.06700        0.36400       11.24300
    ...: H          9.67000       -1.18700       10.48700
    ...: H          9.94500        0.24600        9.48600
    ...: 4
    ...: C:\Users\i4has\Desktop\Test\xa01.pdb
    ...: C         11.30600        1.51100        7.15800
    ...: H         11.68900        1.85800        6.19600
    ...: H         11.53100        2.27500        7.91000
    ...: H         10.21900        1.43100        7.07500 """
```

Note `itertools.islice` takes the same parameters as a regular slice: start, stop and step. Now pretending my string buffer (`io.StringIO`) were a file-object, you should wrap it in a with block:

```
In [23]: with io.StringIO(source) as f:
     ...:     file_it = iter(f)
     ...:     result = []
     ...:     for line in file_it:
     ...:         sub = [l.split() for l in islice(file_it, 1, int(line[0]) + 1)]
     ...:         result.append(sub)
     ...:  

In [24]: result
Out[24]: 
[[['C', '11.74100', '-0.16400', '11.81700'],
  ['H', '10.89900', '-0.07300', '11.12700'],
  ['H', '12.06500', '0.84600', '12.09300'],
  ['H', '11.37900', '-0.66000', '12.72200']],
 [['C', '10.85300', '-0.88000', '9.22400'],
  ['H', '10.72700', '0.08200', '8.72200'],
  ['H', '10.13800', '-0.92800', '10.05300'],
  ['H', '10.59300', '-1.66500', '8.51000']],
 [['C', '11.24200', '-2.12500', '9.34300'],
  ['H', '10.31400', '-1.67400', '8.98400'],
  ['H', '11.00100', '-2.76200', '10.20000'],
  ['H', '11.63100', '-2.76500', '8.54700']],
 [['C', '10.27500', '-0.28000', '10.38600'],
  ['H', '10.06700', '0.36400', '11.24300'],
  ['H', '9.67000', '-1.18700', '10.48700'],
  ['H', '9.94500', '0.24600', '9.48600']],
 [['C', '11.30600', '1.51100', '7.15800'],
  ['H', '11.68900', '1.85800', '6.19600'],
  ['H', '11.53100', '2.27500', '7.91000'],
  ['H', '10.21900', '1.43100', '7.07500']]]
```

Comment: Hi juanpa.arrivillaga,
Thanks for your time and effort. The code works nicely for the given problem but as soon as I gave it another file with more than four atoms, it gave the following error:

sub = [l.split() for l in islice(file_it, 1, int(line[0]) + 1)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'H'

I cannot understand the code in this line how it works (apologies as I am a beginner of Python):
sub = [l.split() for l in islice(file_it, 1, int(line[0]) + 1)]

Can you please explain this line how it works and how can it be made general for any number of atoms present?

Comment: The number of atoms would be mentioned in the first line of any xyz file so we can read them from there and use them. And similarly I do not want the first two lines but the coordinates which would be of similar length for all the chemical structures.

Comment: @Hashmi are you sure the number is always correct? This solution assumes it is.

Comment: @junapa.arrivillaga Thank you so much. It solved the problem. I added a new variable outside the loop to save the first line integer as number of atoms and now it works with all the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in python and i suggest this:

```
lines=open("'vega_str.xyz'","r").readlines()
innerlist=[]
conformers=[]
for line in lines:
        line=line.strip()
        if line.startswith("4") or line.startswith("C:\Users"):
                continue
        coordinates=[x for x in line.split(" ") if x!=""]
        if coordinates[0] == "C" and innerlist:
                conformers.append(innerlist)
                innerlist=[]
        innerlist.append(coordinates)
print conformers
```

output:

```
[[['C', '11.74100', '-0.16400', '11.81700'], ['H', '10.89900', '-0.07300', '11.12700'], ['H', '12.06500', '0.84600', '12.09300'], ['H', '11.37900', '-0.66000', '12.72200']], [['C', '10.85300', '-0.88000', '9.22400'], ['H', '10.72700', '0.08200', '8.72200'], ['H', '10.13800', '-0.92800', '10.05300'], ['H', '10.59300', '-1.66500', '8.51000']], [['C', '11.24200', '-2.12500', '9.34300'], ['H', '10.31400', '-1.67400', '8.98400'], ['H', '11.00100', '-2.76200', '10.20000'], ['H', '11.63100', '-2.76500', '8.54700']], [['C', '10.27500', '-0.28000', '10.38600'], ['H', '10.06700', '0.36400', '11.24300'], ['H', '9.67000', '-1.18700', '10.48700'], ['H', '9.94500', '0.24600', '9.48600']]]
```

Comment: Hi Mani, Thank you very much for your kind reply. Unfortunately, the code is not giving me the same result, rather it gives the following error:
if line.startswith("4") or line.startswith("C:\Users"):
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: And I actually cannot specify the number of atoms as it may be any number which should be written from first line of the xyz file. Also can you tell any other way of skipping the 2nd line as it might also be different depending on the OS it was created. And the last thing that you specified "if coordinates[0] == 'C'" It is also not guaranteed that it will be C. It might be H in another file.
Please help